# How can I Intimidate (demoralize foe) as a Move or Swift action?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, skills, feats

I would like to make Intimidate a major part of my PC's fighting style. I think it's cool, and themey; I don't like the fact that it takes a Standard action, though. Is there any way to speed it up a notch? (Particularly a Feat?) My PC is a beguiler/warblade (gestalt character).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only thing I am aware of in Paizo material is a [Barbarian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian) rage power called `Intimidating Glare`, which allows you to make Intimidate checks as a move action.

Edit: Not directly related to the question, but maybe helpful. The APG has 2 feats that allow you to situationally make free Intimidate checks.

[Dreadful Carnage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/dreadful-carnage-combat) gives you a free Intimidate check when you drop an enemy to 0 or fewer hit points against all enemies within 30 ft.

[Enforcer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/enforcer-combat) Gives you a free Intimidate check against someone when you deal non-lethal damage to them.

Also, those are Pathfinder Specific answers. :)

Comment: +1 for the suggestions. 3.5 material is good, too. Enforcer would work, except that it's marked as Fan Content... not sure what the source of that is? Dreadful Carnage is good too, but kind of situational. I can't use barbarian rage powers (I edited the question to mention my class)

Comment: I think the fan tag is a mistake as it is listed here www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/feat-tree which just has core and apg. but I will double check the apg when I get home.

Comment: Yep, Enforcer is in the APG, page 159. I'll leave 3.5 suggestions to others, as I don't have any of the expansions. (I bought 3 right before they switched and rage-quit D&D for a little while. :()

Comment: I'm marking this because it's the best answer with a couple of options; Bloodsoaked Intimidate is equally good, though. I actually ended up using the Frightful Presence feat, since it doesn't require me to have already killed something - strictly speaking, that doesn't fit the bill posed in the original question, though.

Answer (score 18):

## Demoralizing Quickly

As *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* wound down, it seemed like designers realized the fighter had very little into which it was worthwhile he sink his 1-3 skill points per level. One option was the Intimidate skill, which--unlike many of the fighter's feats--scaled reasonably well. This made the Intimidate skill something for which late-cycle authors wrote quite a few options.

You'll struggle to make use of some of these options if you *stay* exclusively a beguiler//warblade, but the beguiler has the skill Use Magic Device as a class skill, making some of these options more accessible.

- The general feat **Bloodsoaked Intimidate** (*CoR* 17) grants you the ability, as a swift action, to make an Intimidate skill check to demoralize 1 adjacent foe who witnesses you taking a trophy from a fallen foe. *Note:* Not a horrible feat, but has as a prerequisite a feat that has literally no game effects.
- The armor special ability ***fearsome*** (*DrU* 97) (5000 gp; 0 lbs.) grants the wearer the ability, as a move action, to make an Intimidate skill check to demoralize a foe. Further, it grants the wearer a +5 enhancement bonus to Intimidate skill checks and grants the armor spiked armor/armor spikes (*PH* 121, 124). *Note:* Originally published on page 11 of the *Magic Item Compendium* (Mar. 2007) then superseded by *Drow of the Underdark* (May 2007) then *possibly* superseded *again* (with text identical to the original) in the *Magic Item Compendium* (July 2013). Ask the DM.
- The general and fighter feat **Intimidate the Enemy** (*Dragon* #335 91) grants you the ability, as a move action, to make an Intimidate skill check to demoralize a creature. Further add your favored enemy bonus to Intimidate skill checks made to demoralize *versus* creatures of the picked type. The creature type this feat affects must be picked when the feat's gained and the creature type must match one of your favored enemies. *Note:* The regional feat Foe Hunter (*PG* 38-9) grants a creature the ability favored enemy but only *versus* either demons, dragons, goblinoids, orcs, or yuan-ti.
- The general feat **Intimidating Rage** (*CW* 79) grants you the ability, once per encounter as a free action, to make an Intimidate skill check to demoralize 1 foe within 30 ft. You can *only* take the free action while raging. If successful the foe is shaken until your rage ends. *Note:* The shoulders slot item *mantle of rage* (["New Magic Items"](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/MagicItems.pdf) 1) (6,000 gp; 1 lb.) grants the wearer the ability to rage like a Bbn1 1/day. Also, the fiendish symbiont gutworm (*FF* 220) grants its host an ability "identical to a barbarian’s
  rage" at will, but *finding* a gutworm's usually at the DM's discretion. Finally, the drug chiff (*Dragon* #298 46) (300 gp; 0 lbs.), once within 1d3 hours of inhaling it, allows the creature "the ability to Rage [*sic*] (as the barbarian class feature)"; the drug's side effect, overdose effects, and *Addiction: High* make this a risky and expensive workaround.
- The fighter and general feat **Intimidating Strike** (*PH2* 34) grants you the ability, as a free action, to make an to make an Intimidate skill check to demoralize a foe you've struck with a standard attack. You can, before making the standard attack, suffer a cumulative -1 penalty to your attack roll (up to your Base Attack Bonus) to add a cumulative +1 bonus to the Intimidate skill check. *Note:* While not a very good late-game feat, for a creature only making standard attacks anyway *and* who's eligible to use the retraining rules (*PH2* 194), it's actually a decent choice.
- The 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell ***Phade’s fearsome aspect*** [illus] (*Dragon* #333 72) for 1 min./level grants 1 creature a +10 bonus to Disguise skill checks to alter his appearance but not for impersonation, a +5 bonus to Intimidate skill checks, and the ability to take a swift action to make an Intimidate skill check to demoralize a foe.
- The general feat **Supremely Confident** (*Dragon* #334 88) grants you the ability, as a free action, to make an Intimidate skill check to demoralize a foe when you score a critical hit *versus* that foe.
- The level 9 fighter substitution level for **Zhentarim soldier** (*Champions of Valor* Web enhancement ["Benefits of Membership"](https://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060327a) 6-7) grants the creature the extraordinary ability swift demoralization, allowing the creature as a swift action to make an Intimidate skill check to demoralize a foe. *Note:* Although other class features improve a creature's ability to use the skill Intimidate, this is by far the most popular. Comments would suggest it were it omitted, despite it being an unlikely option for a beguiler//warblade.

### For Further Consideration

The following feats, items, spells, and skill trick affect the skill Intimidate in some fashion. Many other treats grant bonuses to the Intimidate skill; I've listed a combination of very good ones and often overlooked ones.

- The throat slot item ***amulet of word twisting*** (*MIC* 71) (6,000 gp; 0 lbs.) grants an orc wearer a +4 insight bonus to Bluff, Diplomacy, Intimidate, and Sense Motive skill checks and the ability to use a command word 1/day to use on himself an effect like the spell *tongues* [div] (*PH* 294). *Note:* Any creature can make a Use Magic Device skill check to emulate the orc race (DC 25) once per hour (*PH* 85-6) to continue to gain this item's benefits; only 1 race can be emulated at a time.
- The perpetual flank tactical maneuver from the tactical feat **Clarion Commander** (*ToB* 34) grants you the ability, as a standard action, to make an Intimidate skill check (DC 20) *versus* 1 foe. If successful, and you make a successful melee attack *versus* that foe next turn, allies treat the foe as flanked for 1 min.
- The slotless item ***clasp of the elder*** (*AE* 131) (6,000 gp; 0 lbs.) grants a dwarf possessor a +2 enhancement bonus to his Wisdom score, a +5 competence bonus to Diplomacy skill checks, and a +5 competence bonus to Intimidate checks. *Note:* Any creature can make a Use Magic Device skill check to emulate the dwarf race (DC 25) once per hour (*PH* 85-6) to continue to gain this item's benefits; only 1 race can be emulated at a time.
- The sneering glower tactical maneuver from the tactical feat **Combat Panache** (*PH2* 93-4) grants you the ability, as a swift action, to make an Intimidate skill check to demoralize a foe you've wounded that, if successful, makes the foe suffer a penalty to attack rolls *versus* you equal to your Charisma bonus's absolute value until the encounter's end or you use the maneuver again.
- The face slot item ***crystal mask of dread*** (*MIC* 91) (10,000; 0.5 lbs.) grants the wearer a +10 competence bonus to Intimidate skill checks.
- The specific magic weapon the ***cudgel that never forgets*** (*MIC* 49-50) (20,312 gp; 8 lbs.) uses its standard action on your turn to make an Intimidate skill check to demoralize a foe. *Note:* Hilariously awesome.
- The 2nd-level Clr spell ***divine presence*** [trans] (*CC* 119) for 10 min./level grants the caster a +5 sacred (if the caster’s good or neutral) or profane bonus to Intimidate skill checks that’s +10 *versus* creatures with one opposed alignment component or +15 *versus* creatures with two.
- The 0th-level Sor/Wiz spell ***fleeting fame*** [illus] (*Dragon* #326 73) for 1 round/level grants the caster a +2 bonus to his next Bluff, Diplomacy, or Intimidate skill check.
- The armor and shield special ability ***hideous*** (*CoR* 40) (3,750 gp; 0 lbs.) grants the wearer a +5 competence bonus to Intimidate skill checks, but the wearer suffers a -2 penalty to Diplomacy skill checks. *Note:* The competence bonus can be increased to +10 (15,000 gp; 0 lbs.) or +15 (33,750 gp; 0 lbs.). Table 7-33 (*DMG* 285) estimates these costs instead should be 10,000 gp and 22,500 gp, respectively. Nope. No idea.
- The general feat **Imperious Command** (*DrU* 50) grants you the ability to make a foe you've successfully demoralized gain the condition [cowering](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#cowering) for 1 round then the condition [shaken](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#shaken) for 1 round. *Note:* In a campaign where the primary foes are *not* immune to fear this feat is problematic, and in a campaign where the primary foes *are* immune to fear this feat is pointless. Ask the DM.
- The alchemical substance **mad foam** (*Dragon* #357 38-9) (25 gp; 0.25 lbs.) for 2d6 minutes grants a canine a +2 bonus to Intimidate skill checks; the canine's obvious master also gains this bonus.
- The skill trick **Never Outnumbered** (*CAd* 87) grants you the ability, once per encounter, to make an Intimidate skill check to demoralize all foes within 10 ft.
- The item quality **ornate** (*Dragon* #358 42) (400 gp for light armor, 500 gp for a weapon, 600 gp for heavy armor; 0 lbs.) grants the armor's wearer or the weapon's wielder either a +2 circumstance bonus to Diplomacy skill checks or a +2 circumstance bonus to Intimidate skill checks, chosen when the quality is applied. *Note:* Circumstance bonuses stack (*DMG* 21) if circumstances differ; talk to the DM.
- The 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell ***rain of terror*** [necro] (*Dragon* #348 76) for 1 min./level grants the caster a +10 bonus to Intimidate skill checks. *Note:* My personal favorite *D&D 3.X* spell.
- The 1st-level Rgr spell ***towering oak*** [illus] (*SpC* 221) as a swift action for 1 round/level grants the caster a +2 enhancement bonus to Strength and a +10 competence bonus to Intimidate skill checks. *Note:* Also a 1st-level consecrated harrier (*CD* 28) spell with a minimum caster level 1.
- The drug **vodare** (*BoVD* 43-4) (40 gp; 0 lbs.) for 1d4 hours grants a +2 alchemical bonus to Intimidate skill checks. *Note:* Even *fantasy* cocaine makes your character act like a jerk.
- The 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell ***voice of the dragon*** [ench] (*SpC* 232) for 10 min./level grants the caster the ability to speak but not read the language Draconic and a +10 enhancement bonus to Bluff, Diplomacy, and Intimidate skill checks. As a standard action that otherwise ends the spell he can use an effect like the spell *suggestion* [ench] (*PH* 285).

Comment: To readers with short attention spans, who may have skipped past: This answer is great, comprehensive, and **worthy of its length**. +1, would read again.

Comment: Although downvotes never *need* to be explained, I'd like to make this answer more useful, and if I've made a mistake I'd like to correct it. Feedback *really is* appreciated.

Comment: Note: **Supremely Confident** is actually in Dragon Magazine 335.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I am so sorry if I sent you on a wild goose chase. My apologies.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: Oh don't be, at least with the feat name I could look it up; before reading this answer I didn't even know it existed!

Answer (score 4):

For DnD 3.5. There is the feat **Bloodsoaked Intimidate** from the book **Champions of Ruin**. This is where you can use intimidate as a swift action.

Answer (score 1):

[Cornugon Smash](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cornugon-smash-combat/) (Combat)
Prerequisites: Power Attack, Intimidate 6 ranks.
Benefit: When you damage an opponent with a Power Attack, you may make an **immediate** Intimidate check as a **free action** to attempt to demoralize your opponent.
This is one is fun to add to it... [Hurtful](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/hurtful-combat/) (Combat)
Prerequisite(s): Str 13, Power Attack.
Benefit(s): When you successfully demoralize an opponent within your melee reach with an Intimidate check, you can make a single melee attack against that creature as a swift action. If your attack fails to damage the target, its shaken condition from being demoralized immediately ends.